# Why windows.h disables pack warning?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-alignment

In `windows.h` file there is the following lines :

```
#ifndef __WINDOWS_DONT_DISABLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WARNING__
#pragma warning(disable:4103)
#endif
```

I discovered we have pragma pack warning after re-ordering some include file. The risk of having a bad alignment seems serious. Why whould Microsoft disable this warning ?

Comment: Ask Microsoft? Its their header.

Comment: Including `Windows.h` is something you do out of necessity.  Best avoided if possible.  For reasons such as this.

Comment: Or define `__WINDOWS_DONT_DISABLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WARNING__`.

Comment: It is in general necessary to make the PshPackx.h and PopPack.h #include files work without them generating level 1 warnings.  They get a lot of use in the SDK headers.  Focus on asking a question about the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking "why did X do Y".

Comment: @HansPassant I want to define __WINDOWS_DONT_DISABLE_PRAGMA_PACK_WARNING__ but I'd like to know if there is any reasons no to do so.

Comment: @Chad: What???? `#include <windows.h>` is the recommended way to access any and all Windows OS functionality, you're not supposed to include more specific headers.

Comment: Windows OS functionality, when you need to interact directly with Windows (a la HWND, HANDLE, etc.) it is necessary.  However, `Windows.h` brings in all kinds of things that are typically unnecessary.  So better to avoid it unless you really need that functionality.

Comment: @Chad: You can define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` to avoid those.  But you can't avoid including windows.h

Answer (score 5):

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4d0762d.aspx).

Essentially, windows.h includes a number sub-headers many of them defining structs that remaps some hardware defined fields (so, no padding is required)

Since the push/pop are not done on every sub-include, it disables the 4103 warning to avoid spurious warning to come out.

MS itself recommend to include windows.h as first or last include, but not intermixing it. Not a great choice, but consider windows.h is around from 25+ years and some of the function and struct it defines are still the same... and some other cannot be reworked without breaking existing app.

`<windows.h>` itself ensures the proper restoring by ensuring all the involved sub-headers you should not include yourself directly are included in the proper order.

If you enable that warning you will see all those internal mismatches windows.h is masking out.

Comment: An important missing detail is whether windows.h itself preserves (via push/pop) the packing option.

Comment: The `#pragma push/pop` feature is more recent than `#pragma pack`.  There are a number of sub-headers that set packing without push/pop and other that do only push assuming another one will do the corresponding pop.

windows.h itself ensures proper pairing, but if you enable that warning, you will see the mismatches in subheaders you should not include yourself directly.

Comment: Understood, but what everyone needs to know and you did not answer is "Will `#include <windows.h>` change the effective structure packing, or does it restore the setting in effect beforehand?"  Regardless of how many subheaders are involved.

Comment: I wish I could +1 again, that is a great and complete answer.

Comment: windows.h should do `pragma warning(push)` and `warning(pop)` instead of disabling this warning for the including file. Also, I defined the macro to enable that warning and I didn't see any new warning coming from windows.h (visual 2010). I will double check tomorrow though